# Jafa FX CSS Duplicates

Tags: javafx, javafx-css

I am new to JavaFX and CSS Styling and was just after some clarification on the optimal way to do the following.

Essentially, I have two buttons which I have implemented Hover and Focus so the Border Color changes on both Hover (mouse) and Focused (Key Board Tab).  Currently I have the following :

```css
.normalbutton:hover {

    -fx-font-size: 11pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Verdana";
    -fx-font-weight : Normal;

    -fx-background-color : #545454;

    -fx-border-color: #FFFFFF ;
    -fx-border-radius: 3,3,3,3;
    -fx-border-width: 1px ;

}

.normalbutton:focused {

     -fx-font-size: 11pt;
     -fx-font-family: "Verdana";
     -fx-font-weight : Normal;

     -fx-background-color : #545454;

     -fx-border-color: #FFFFFF ;
     -fx-border-radius: 3,3,3,3;
     -fx-border-width: 1px ;

}
```

It works fine but I wan wondering if there was a way to combine both focused and hover as they have the same properties.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple selectors can be seperated by `,` in CSS. If one of them matches, the the style is applied. In your example it would look like this:

```css
.normalbutton:hover,
.normalbutton:focused {

     -fx-font-size: 11pt;
     -fx-font-family: "Verdana";
     -fx-font-weight : Normal;

     -fx-background-color : #545454;

     -fx-border-color: #FFFFFF ;
     -fx-border-radius: 3,3,3,3;
     -fx-border-width: 1px ;

}
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping